# XAMPP MySql PHPAdmin

Tags: mysql, xampp

I did everything but still getting the error: 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\user_preferences.lib.php on line 12

What i did:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
max_allowed_packet = 200M (in my.ini)
```

I am using:
Windows 10 Home

Can anyone helpi please?

Answer (score 0):

The time limit in my.ini file is for MySQL. The error is related to time limit in PHP settings. I'm not sure but try this in your C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\user_preferences.lib.php file

```
set_time_limit(yourTimeLimite e.g 100);
```